# GitLab CI with Postgres ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: node.js, postgresql, gitlab, sequelize.js, gitlab-ci

I have a `Gitlab CI pipeline` which tests, builds and deploys code.
The code is basically a nodejs api and database is managed using `Sequelize ORM`.
Recently, I tried the pipeline with a `Postgres Database`.

Here is the `gitlab-ci.yml` file :

```
image: trion/ng-cli-karma

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: test
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  NODE_ENV: test

cache:
  paths:
  - wiki-quotes-client/node_modules/
  - wiki-quotes-server/node_modules/

stages:
    - test
    - build
    - deploy

test_server:
  services:
   - postgres:latest
  script:
   - cd wiki-quotes-server
   - npm install
   - npm install -g sequelize-cli
   - sequelize db:migrate
   - sequelize db:seed:all
   - npm run test

test_client:
    script:
        -  cd wiki-quotes-client
        -  npm install
        -  ng test --watch=false

build_angular:
  only:
    - master
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - cd wiki-quotes-client
    - ng build --prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - wiki-quotes-client/dist/wiki-quotes-client/.

deploy:
  only:
    - master
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build_angular
  script:
    - ls -all
    - apt-get update -qq
    - apt-get install -qq git
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - ls ~/.ssh/
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\t StrictHostKeyChecking no \n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - ssh-keyscan 159.65.156.240 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh goutambseervi@159.65.156.240 'cd ~/wikiquotesapp; git checkout master; git pull;  cd wiki-quotes-server; npm install; npm start:prod'
```

Now it shows me this error :

> **ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432**

Also, additional question I had was...

What would be the ideal path to follow when I'm deploying a api with a database using `Sequelize` ?

I want to make sure that my migrations go live and at the same time my database should be seeded everytime I deploy and I don't want the database to have redundant data.

Comment: You should remove the password from your question.

Answer (score 4):

Using services in Gitlab CI works basically the same way as running different docker containers (named services in docker-compose) that are made available to your container running the specific job.

So according to your error message I assume your code tries to reach the postgres database on `localhost` which works when you run both on your developer machine. In Gitlab CI these are two containers that "have both their own `localhost`" and must use dns names like `postgres` to connect to another container. So as you are using an image called `postgres`, Gitlab also names the service like that.

Please try using the hostname `postgres` instead of `localhost` for your database connection in the node process and the access should work. According to your other variables defined, this may already work by just adding one more `variable` of `POSTGRES_HOST: postgres` (or similar - I'm not familiar with sequelize config)

For details on services in Gitlab CI please check [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html) that even provide a sample for your specific use case of accessing a `postgres` service and [some clarification on this specific question](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-services-are-linked-to-the-job).